How do we know when UWP slider starts moving before the value change?
Overview
I have a project with UWP technology, where I use slider control, to collect information about slider moves I used the ManipulationStarting (for the beginning of the move) and ManipulationEnding (for the end of the move) events.
Main Problem 
The issue emerged when the users clicked on the slider line to change its value immediately instead of the slider movements. In this case, ManipulationStarting event was not invoked and broke my architectural logic.
What I have tried to solve this problem ` 

During my research, I have found these solutions that do not match my problem or are not optimal. (Link1 , Link2)
I have also used the PointerReleased/PointerPress event but this one gets invoked only after ValueChanged event
I have created my custom slider class which derives from UWP slider and override the base’s property and in Set method before the value initialization I invoke ValueChanging event(see code below). But in case of using the Binding only the base property is used and my overridden property gets skipped.

    public class TestSlider : Slider
    {
        public event EventHandler ValueChanging;
        
        public new double Value
        {
            get => (this as Slider).Value;
            set 
            {
                ValueChanging?.Invoke( this, new EventArgs());
                (this as Slider).Value = value;
            }
        } }

Can you help me find another way to solve this problem?
